# Fortran: makefile with already compiled modules

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran

I have a project structure like this

```
-Project

 --Common

  ---types.f90

  ---global.f90

  ---common_routines.f90

 --Program 1

  ---program1.f90

  ---module1.f90

  ---module2.f90

  ---etc...

 --Program 2

 --etc...
```

Where, Common is folder that contains some modules that are shared across all programs. How do I include this modules on my makefile?

I tried this:

```
FC = gfortran
FCFLAGS = -fbounds-check -O3
FCFLAGS += -I ../Common

all: program1

program1: module1.o module2.o module3.o

program1.o: module1.o module2.o module3.o

module2.o: module1.o

module3.o: module2.o module1.o

%: %.o
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $^ 

%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.mod
```

but I get an undefined reference error to the common modules variables.

Comment: Is that an "undefined reference" at link time (you don't seem to link against any object files corresponding to the modules)?

Comment: To be more precise: you should change `%: %.o` to include the common modules.

Comment: How do I do this? I tried   `FCFLAGS += -I../Common types.o global.o common_routines.o` but now I have `no rule to make target types.o need by module1.o.Stop.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried FCFLAGS += -I../Common types.o global.o common_routines.o

This will not work because `-I` is an option to the GNU Fortran preprocessor 
to specify a path that the preprocessor shall search for files to be INCLUDE-ed
prior to *compilation*. You cannot use it to specify a path where *object* files (`*.o`) 
will be searched for, after compilation, by the *linker*. It means nothing to 
the linker and is not passed to the linker.

For simplicity let's assume that the object files you need to to link for
`program1` are just `program1/program1.o` plus the pre-existing `common/types.o`,
`common/global.o` and `common/common_routines.o`

Then the following `Makefile`, placed in directory `program1`, will build it:

```
OBJS = program1.o ../common/types.o ../common/global.o ../common/common_routines.o

.phony: all

all: program1

program1: program1.o
    $(FC) -o $@ $(FCFLAGS) $(OBJS) 

clean:
    rm -f *.o program1
```

Just list all the required object files to the linker, in this case via `$(OBJS)`

You might wish to take the precaution of making sure that the common modules
are up to date before you build `program1`, and you now might think that you can do that
simply be replacing:

```
program1: program1.o
```

with:

```
program1: $(OBJS)
```

thus prompting `make` to recompile *any* of the four object files that is out
of date with respect to the corresponding source file, as a prerequisite of
building `program1`

`make` will certainly endeavour to do that, but take care. That way, it will
recompile, say, `../common/types.o` from `../common/types.f90` just by its
implicit default recipe for making an `.o` from an `.f90`, since this makefile is
not telling it to do any different. But that may not be the way in which
`../common/types.f90` is meant to be compiled, if you also have is a makefile in `common`
that stipulates how to do it in some non-default manner.

In that case, the common object files should always be compiled as per the
makefile in `common`. Better leave the prerequisites of `program1` alone but change the recipe to:

```
program1: program1.o
    $(MAKE) -C ../common
    $(FC) -o $@ $(FCFLAGS) $(OBJS)
```

Now, any time `program1` needs to be rebuilt, the recipe will preemptively run `make` in `../common`
before it links the four object files. (It's a small inelegance that this `$(MAKE) -C ../common`
will be invoked even if there's nothing for it to do: this is avoidable by more advanced `make` usage).

Lastly you might also find a need (if not in this case, then in another) to distinguish 
between flags passed to *preprocessing* and/or flags passed to *compilation* and/or flags passed to *linkage*.
Conventionally, these are assigned to distinct `make` variables, e.g. `FPPFLAGS` (preprocessor), 
`FCFLAGS` (compiler), `LDFLAGS` (linker).

Answer (score 0):

The [GNU syntax to define additional include directory](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gfortran/Directory-Options.html) is `-Idir` not `-I dir` (extra space)

Also make sure that common modules are already [compiled](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gfortran/Directory-Options.html) and include search path points to the directory where you have compiled modules, not source files:

> This path is also used to search for .mod files when previously compiled modules are required by a USE statement.